# How to substitute the solution of the derivative in wxMaxima?

Tags: wxmaxima

I am trying to substitute the value of the first derivative in the equation with wxMaxima.  The substitution steps works fine with simple algebra but it does not work with derivative. It also substitutes the second derivative but I want to see first derivative replaced only.  Where I am doing wrong?

```
 (%i5)  kill(all);
 (%o0)  done
 (%i5)  eq1:diff(y(x),x)+(a*x+b*y(x))=0;
 (eq1)  'diff(y(x),x,1)+b*y(x)+a*x=0
 (%i6)  eq2:diff(eq1,x);
 (eq2)  'diff(y(x),x,2)+b*('diff(y(x),x,1))+a=0
 (%i7)  eq3:solve(eq1,diff(y(x),x));
 (eq3)  ['diff(y(x),x,1)=-b*y(x)-a*x]
 (%i9)  eq5:subst(eq3,eq4),derivsubst=true;
 (eq5)  ['diff((-(b*y(x)+a*x+c)/(%beta*y(x)+%alpha*x+%gamma)),x,1)=-(-(((%alpha*b-%beta*a)*x-%beta*c+%gamma*b)*(b*y(x)+a*x+c)/(%beta*y(x)+%alpha*x+%gamma)+    (%beta*a-%alpha*b)*y(x)-%alpha*c+%gamma*a)/(%beta^2*y(x)^2(2*%alpha*%beta*x+2*%gamma*%beta)*y(x)+%alpha^2*x^2+2*%gamma*%alpha*x+%gamma^2)]('diff(y(x),x,1))+a=0)
 (%i5)  test:a-2*v=v+2-a;
 (test) a-2*v=v-a+2
 (%i6)  test2:solve(test,a);
 (test2)    [a=(3*v+2)/2]
 (%i7)  subst([test2], a+b);
 (%o7)  (3*v+2)/2+b
```

Comment: Can you point out which are the results which are not working out as you expected, and what you were expecting in each case? Thanks for any info.

Comment: I see that you have `eq4:subs(...)`, did you mean to say `eq4:subst(...)` ?

Comment: yes, it should be subst

Comment: OK, if subs is changed to subst, do you get the expected result? If not, maybe you can say what you're expecting.